# .vs/slnx.sqlite exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I can't push feature/rental-map getting this error:

```
! [remote rejected] feature/rental-map -> feature/rental-map (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:saeefahmed/bwm-ng.git'
```

How can I get past that error message?

Comment: FYI, all the`.vs` folder should be ignored and so not committed. Update your not pushed history like @Vonc answer told you to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Answer (score 0):

That is why, for instance, [Heroku reminds us to ignore such large files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/gitignore#ignoring-sqlite-files)

```
git rm -f db/*.sqlite3
echo '*.sqlite3' > .gitignore
git add .gitignore
git commit -m "ignored sqlite databases"
```

But, if that still does not work, then you need to remove the file from *all* commit: I would recommend [BFG Repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

```
java -jar bfg.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
cd some-big-repo.git
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

And then `git push --force`, which is OK if you are the only one working on that repo.